# Get element text from this span using Selenium WebDriver and C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, webdriver

I have exhausted my mental resources and can't solve this puzzle. I am attempting to extract the text from the span with id = "lookupCount". I want the "9" from there, but no matter how hard I try, it doesn't work. Please help, below is the html.

Just to be clear, i want the value of this text - "9"

```html
<div class="addressSelectionDiv" style="width:330px; margin-left:0px; margin-top:40px; ">
<table id="addressSelectionTable" align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15px;">
<td>
<div id="App.ctl00_leftContent_addressSelection_validationLabel_Container" style="display:inline;">
<label id="ctl00_leftContent_addressSelection_validationLabel" class="x-label x-label-default x-border-box" for="" style="color:#981e32;font-size:1.0em;">
<img id="ext-gen1029" class="x-label-icon" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" style="display: none;"/>
<span id="ext-gen1030" class="x-label-value"/>
</label>
</div>
<span id="lookups" style="visibility: hidden; float: right;">
<span id="lookupCount">9</span>
/
<span id="lookupLimit">100</span>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is what I tried

- `var x = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lookupCount")).Text`     returns ""
- `var x = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lookups")).Text` returns ""
- Neither of the objects above contain any information that leads me to the answer, even if I remove the .Text property.
- The 2 lines below returns "" in the [0]th element.

`ICollection<IWebElement> table = Driver.FindElements(By.Id("lookups"));
List<IWebElement> elements = table.ToList();`

The one below returns this string:

`Search for Household Decisions by entering an address or ZIP code:\r\n\r\n AL\r\n AK\r\n AZ\r\n AR\r\n CA\r\n CO\r\n CT\r\n DC\r\n DE\r\n FL\r\n GA\r\n HI\r\n ID\r\n IL\r\n IN\r\n IA\r\n KS\r\n KY\r\n LA\r\n ME\r\n MD\r\n MA\r\n MI\r\n MN\r\n MS\r\n MO\r\n MT\r\n NE\r\n NV\r\n NH\r\n NJ\r\n NM\r\n NY\r\n NC\r\n ND\r\n OH\r\n OK\r\n OR\r\n PA\r\n RI\r\n SC\r\n SD\r\n TN\r\n TX\r\n UT\r\n VT\r\n VA\r\n WA\r\n WV\r\n WI\r\n WY`

`ICollection<IWebElement> table = Driver.FindElements(By.Id("addressSelectionTable"));
List<IWebElement> elements = table.ToList();`

Comment: I tried everything I could think of: using "addressSelectionTable" to get the elements and loop through them, returned only a bunch of text that wasn't relevant for my purpose. Using id="lookups" to read the text. using 'id=lookupCount' to see any values. All like this, "Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lookupCount")).Text", just changing the Id. They either return a string of text not relevant for my purpose or a "".

Answer (score 0):

Returns text located between open/close tag of the element with Id "lookupCount":

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("lookupCount")).Text;
```

Returns html code between open/close tag with id "lookupCount":

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("lookupCount")).HtmlInner;
```

Comment: maybe better to add some explain in your answer

Comment: Returns "". I wouldn't have come here if it was that simple. Also, no HtmlInner property.

Comment: Looks like you did something wrong or you have something wrong with your environment, as the same code working good enough on my side: http://prntscr.com/7y1246 This is the same code, but wrapped to another classes and methods.

Comment: @Andrew what do you think is up with the environment? I fee like that should work as well

Comment: @user1579407, have no idea. But this code is working good on my side, as you see on the screenshot.